# How can disable tap gesture in parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have 2 views. View 1 is superview and i added tap gesture in superview. View 2 is Collectionview and when I click on collectionview cell both event didSelectItemAt in Collectionview and tap gesture in superview called.How can disable tap gesture in supperview when I click on collectionview cell?

Comment: Do you have code that can help us duplicate things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` on your parent view.

E.g `view.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Docs at [userInteractionEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-userinteractionenabled)

--UPDATE

You can implement [gestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624214-gesturerecognizer) delegate,a nd then check if it is your view that called on `touch` property;

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view == {{youview}} {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: But i need tapgesture when i click outside collectionviewcell and if you set userInteractionEnabled = false in parentview you can't click on collectionview because collectionvew inside parent view